# Is there any predefined standard function for lambda x: x in Python?

Tags: python, lambda, operators

For example, `lambda x, y: x + y` has it's equivalent standard function `operator.add`.

Is there any predefined standard function for `lambda x: x` as such?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking; can you explain where you need this?

Comment: Surely there is an equivalent one `lambda x: x` == `x`.

Comment: There is no  built-in identity function. the `operator` module provides many function forms of python operators, and a few utility function. There is no identity operator in Python.

Comment: @Sraw not really. `lambda x: x` is callable. `x` need not be, and even if it were, it doesn't necessarily behave like the identity function. It doesn't even really make sense to say that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no build in function but you can write it on your own some kind of "Buffer gate" with this rules:
[Buffer Gate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBPDu.jpg)

Or like this using double negation (but is there really a point?):
[Double negation gates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOx2Q.jpg)

Source: www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-3/buffer-gate/

Comment: But the question is not about two logical states and corresponding electrical circuits.

Comment: So tere is also an answer "There is no build in function".
As @juanpa.arrivillaga said "X" is not collable so we need to write yours own function. So what is programming in if not operating on logical states?

Comment: `lambda x:x` is an identity function working for any value, not only True/False logical states.